# Phone Number Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

Basically I am looking for a regular expression for phone numbers.

Inputs can be:

```
009133434343443434
+92333232323232
0223323232
0345*
021*
```

What I have tried

```
^\(?([0-9]{3})\)?[-. ]?([0-9]{3})[-. ]?([0-9]{4})$
```

Maximum number of characters in my field can be 20 and least number of fields can be 3 but by the above reg ex i am unable to find appropriate results.

`*` can only come in end
`+` can only come at the start of string.

Comment: Might want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123559/a-comprehensive-regex-for-phone-number-validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to understand regex from this site : http://www.wellho.net/regex/java.html

check out the regex library here for addresses and phone numbers: http://regexlib.com/DisplayPatterns.aspx?cattabindex=6&categoryId=7

(refresh that last site to get phone number patterns at the beginning.)

Answer (score 0):

I have worked for it and now its working fine for me thanks to All for such a fast response specially saher

```
^[+ .]?[01]?[01]?\(?[2-9]\d{1,15}\)?[*]*$
```